# What's i in url like http://i.imgur.com/hmb4y.jpg?

Tags: php, image

I'm digging into html code on imgur, and I've seen an url `http://i.imgur.com/hmb4y.jpg` containing `i`, what is `i`? Is it folder or not? How can i create an url like this for my site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a [subdomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain) of the main `imgur.com` domain. Specifically this one (`i`) was defined to host images for StackOverflow. To create an url like this for your site you will have to register a subdomain at the company from which you purchased the root domain or if it is for intranet only you could do this in your DNS server or the *hosts* file.

Comment: Thanks, How I can create that i subdomain on my localhost?

Comment: @michael, if you use Apache, here's a tutorial: http://digitalpbk.blogspot.com/2007/01/making-subdomains-on-localhost.html

Comment: Thanks Darin! Does I contains millions of pictures? Is it a folder on the server?

Comment: @michael, it depends on how you map it. It usually corresponds to a physical folder on the server. Read the tutorial I linked to.